# check multiple combination query mongodb

Tags: json, database, mongodb

I have a collection like below in mongodb.

```
{ 
    "_id" : "kzNRRctKpXa49S4pW", 
    "from" : NumberInt(1), 
    "to" : 5.1, 
    "price" : NumberInt(76)
}
{ 
    "_id" : "JbQGobyPiYhqNm2hB", 
    "from" : 5.1, 
    "to" : 5.2, 
    "price" : NumberInt(1)
}
```

**I want to insert new combination that must be**

- different of **from** and **to**.

**How can I check that before  the insert?**

> For Example: If there is already value
>
> - from: 5.1
> - to: 5.5  it must not insert new **from** and **to** between or equal to same value

I have to insert unique value like.

> From     To      Price
>    5.1         5.5    5
>   5.6         6.5    10
>   0.1         0.2   1
>   0.6         0.8   2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try "$gte" and "$lte" operators in mongodb. From the documentation

```
$gte selects the documents where the value of the field is greater than
or equal to (i.e. >=) a specified value 

$lte selects the documents where the value of the field is less than or
equal to (i.e. <=) the specified value.

Python:
collection.find({"from":{"$gte": 5.6},  "to": {"$lte": 7.5}}))
```

This query will only selects documents where "from" is greater than or equal to 5.6 and "to" is greater than or equal to 7.5.

Comment: it will not help my issue

Comment: You can check the results of these queries, if they return empty results, you can insert the new document, if not, then document with that conditions already exists.

Comment: It will not work when i need to insert value like

From    to
0.5       1.5 

but i want to insert these value also

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: How  from to 0.5 1.5 lies between  5.1
to: 5.5 ?

Comment: 0.5 1.5 don't lies between 5.1 to: 5.5 but  i have to insert new value that don't lies in existing combination

Answer (score 0):

Add a compound unique index on your two fields, this way your inserts will fail if combination already exists.

```
db['coll'].createIndex( { "from": 1, "to": 1 }, { unique: true } );
```

Comment: This will not handle the greater than condition.

Comment: But it will insert value like

5.1       5.5
5.2        5.3   But i don't want to allow this type of value